# Windows 7: route to connect to VPN via Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, vpn, routing

I have a corporate Windows 7 machine that is supposed to connect to a VPN but for some reason the Cisco software won't connect and none of the gurus at the corporation have been able to figure this out.

I have the VPN connected via Linux that contains this route to the VPN network:

```
10.169.64.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.192.0  ... tun0
```

The local Linux machine is

```
192.168.1.113
```

so I added this route on the Windows 7 machine:

```
route -p add 10.169.64.0/18 192.168.1.113
```

and that was added correctly ... but I can't connect to the 10.169 network.

I was thinking that if Linux has the route, then all I'd need to do would be to connect to Linux to get the connection passed through. But do I need an intermediate route to the internal IP of the VPN and not directly to the tunnel address?

Please advise. Thanks much for any help!

Comment: Is the local machine Linux machine configured for forwarding? If not, the Windows 7 machine will have send packets for the Linux machine, and the Linux machine will just drop them. (Google for instructions how to enable forwarding).

Comment: I edited the **/etc/sysctl.conf** file in Linux to enable routing and also installed the **quagga** package that enables RIPD routing. Still no good.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I'd like to comment but have not enough rep. so this goes as a pseudo-answer at most:

- what does `tracert -d 10.169.64.1` (or some other host that you expect to be able to ping on the remote side of your vpn) on your windows machine say?
- does the remote vpn gateway know about a whole subnet sitting behind its peer, or is this normally supposed to be a client-to-site connection? (in the latter case you will need to NAT your local subnet behind the linux machine's vpn ip address)
- which type of vpn is this? IPsec uses "SAs" to decide which traffic to allow inside a tunnel, openVPN needs special server-side config (pushing routes etc) to make this work, etc.
- check `ifconfig tun0` output on your linux machine. I'd bet that it has some different ip address on the tunnel interface? This is your ip to masquerade your local subnet behind.

hope this helps.